Don't send push notification when my app updates a file
I have an application that creates and updates files with the drive.file scope.
And I have a changes.watch channel watching for any changes.
The API's version is google-api-services-drive : v3-rev20220815-2.0.0.
I am using Java and this is how I start the channel, as soon as the user authorize:
Channel channel = new Channel()
                    .setId("my-channel-id")
                    .setType("web_hook")
                    .setExpiration(System.currentTimeMillis() + 604800000) //one week later
                    .setAddress("https://mydomain/mycontext/notifications");

String startPageToken = driveService.changes().getStartPageToken().execute().getStartPageToken();
driveService.changes().watch(startPageToken, channel).setIncludeRemoved(Boolean.TRUE).execute();

This is how I update a file:
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("new name");
driveService.files().update("myFileId", fileMetadata).execute();

Is there a way of not sending the notification when this update by my application ocurrs?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
